# Browser Caching of CSS files

Tags: html, css, http, caching, browser

Quick question regarding CSS and the browser. I tried searching SO and found some similar posts, but nothing definitive.

I use one or two CSS files in my web projects. These are referenced in the HEAD of my web pages. Once I hit one of my pages, does the CSS get cached so that it's not re-downloaded with each request? I hope so. Do IE, Firefox and Safari handle this differently? If the browser is closed, is the CSS refreshed on the first visit when a new browser instance is opened?

Comment: The "file size" part of the title is a bit misleading, as the actual question don't actually revolve around file sizes at all. "CSS files and Browser Caching" or "Browser Caching of CSS files" look like much better titles... </twocents>

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your file will *probably* be cached - but it depends...

Different browsers have slightly different behaviors - most noticeably when dealing with ambiguous/limited caching headers emanating from the server. If you send a clear signal, the browsers obey, virtually all of the time.

The greatest variance by far, is in the default caching configuration of different web servers and application servers.

Some (e.g. Apache) are likely to serve known static file types with HTTP headers encouraging the browser to cache them, while other servers may send `no-cache` commands with every response - regardless of filetype.

...

So, first off, read some of the excellent [HTTP caching tutorials](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) out there. [HTTP Caching & Cache-Busting
for Content Publishers](http://www.radwin.org/michael/talks/http-caching.ppt) was a real eye opener for me :-)

Next install and fiddle around with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) and the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) add-on , to find out which headers your server is actually sending.

Then read your web server docs to find out how to tweak them to perfection (or talk your sysadmin into doing it for you).

...

As to what happens when the browser is restarted, it depends on the browser and the user configuration.

As a rule of thumb, expect the browser to be more likely to check in with the server after each restart, to see if anything has changed (see [If-Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) and [If-None-Match](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26)).

If you configure your server correctly, it should be able to return a super-short [304 Not Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) (costing very little bandwidth) and after that the browser will use the cache as normal.

Comment: Does Ctrl-K already show us the "live http headers"? Why do we need to use Live HTTP Header add-on?

Answer (score 48):

To the first part of your question - yes, browsers cache css files (if this is not disabled by browser's configuration). Many browsers have key combination to reload a page without a cache.
If you made changes to css and want users to see them immediately instead of waiting next time when browser reloads the files without caching, you can change the way CSS ir served by adding some parameters to the url like this:

```
/style.css?modified=20012009
```

Comment: Genius! /Style.css?deployment={DeploymentId}

Comment: Is this behavior supported by the RFC?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, this is a "supported" way to do things. Since the browser just sees `/style.css?modified=20012009` as a URL, it is equivalent to changing the name of your CSS file every time you do a release. Since the browser thinks the file is new, it will not try to use any cached version of it.

Comment: @plowman, I mean yes it's working in the *wild*, but is the behavior actually supported by the official prescriptive rfc standards?

Comment: @Pacerier - Looks like a pretty standard HTTP GET parameter to me. What makes you think it would not be supported? Nothing special going on here...

Answer (score 9):

It does depend on the HTTP headers sent with the CSS files as both of the previous answers state - as long as you don't append any cachebusting stuff to the href. e.g.

```
<link href="/stylesheets/mycss.css?some_var_to_bust_cache=24312345" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Some frameworks (e.g. rails) put these in by default.

However If you get something like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/), you can see exactly what your browser is downloading on each request - which is expecially useful for finding out what your browser *is* doing, as opposed to just what it *should* be doing.

All browsers *should* respect the cache headers in the same way, unless configured to ignore them (but there are bound to be exceptions)

Answer (score 3):

It's probably worth noting that IE won't cache css files called by other css files using the @import method. So, for example, if your html page links to "master.css" which pulls in "reset.css" via @import, then reset.css will not be cached by IE.

Comment: This seems like an extremely important point. Can you add a reference?

Comment: This dosn't seems to be true, cf.: [link](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/) see  this comment/answer:

Murray | 27-May-09 at 9:52 am 
Steve,
I’ve also heard that when using @ import, browsers may not cache the css files, unlike with a . But I haven’t been able to verify this. Are you aware if it actually matters from a caching perspective? If so, it might be another reason to avoid @ import.

Steve Souders | 27-May-09 at 2:26 pm 
Murray: I haven’t heard that and it doesn’t happen in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what headers you are sending along with your CSS files. Check your server configuration as you are probably not sending them manually.
Do a google search for "http caching" to learn about different caching options you can set.
You can force the browser to download a fresh copy of the file everytime it loads it for instance, or you can cache the file for one week...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've messed with your server, yes it's cached.  All the browsers are supposed to handle it the same.  Some people (like me) might have their browsers configured so that it doesn't cache any files though.  Closing the browser doesn't invalidate the file in the cache.  Changing the file on the server should cause a refresh of the file however.

Comment: This is mostly wrong. There are differences between browsers regarding caching. And once a file is cached on the client it won't be downloaded again until the cache (for whatever reason) expires, changing the file on the server will not make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

Browser cache is one thing.

But second thing is server(s) cache(s). If your server support CDN service (Content Delivery Network), your webpage files could be cached on one or more servers. Even if you clear browser cache, add version or other parameters to linkrel url, your and other users' browsers will be still loading page from the server cache, not from the updates files.

I have this problem with my server which has turned on CDN by default. Every time I update some css files need clear server cache otherwise browser still loading old version. There is a special button in server control panel called "CLEAN CDN CACHE". After that page is loading updated and I am sure the same is for other users. Check control panel of your server for similar option or write to server support team how to turn of CDN or not allow for caching.

It can be also helpful a .htaccess file with settings:

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, private, must-revalidate"
```

It not allow for caching files. But I dont know it will work with every server type (with Apache should).