# CSS caching Chrome VS Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, page-load-time

I have a problem with CSS caching in Firefox. I'm creating a website which includes a frame within the page. 
However, I don't know why, but there's a big difference between loading time from the page and from the frame.

More surprising, it doesn't happens on Chrome, only in Firefox. That's the reason why I'm suspecting Firefox having a different CSS cache system than Chrome.

As it's .LESS CSS, I though that this was because the .less was compiled and it took a lot of time. But I can't find out why this only happens on Firefox. If it was due to the compiling time for the .less, it would also happen on Chrome, isn't it ?

Does someone have some clues ?

Thanks

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460389/browser-caching-of-css-files

Comment: Do you have an example we could look at? Also are you processing the LESS before you send it to browser (i.e. don't rely on less.js to do it for you client side)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any online example. What I can say is that on my network tracker with Firebug, the page loads in 75 ms and then, a big "hole" before 1-2 seconds. I guess that this is the compiling time for the LESS. 

On top of that, In my Javascript debug, I have this message : 
Error: Couldn't load http://localhost:2014/m/style.css (404) @ http://localhost:2014/m/pinax/js/less.js:8.
What is disturbing me is that I don't have any /m/ folder. Is this included with Django ?
Obviously, this is why it takes so long to load.