# unusual link to external style sheet

Tags: html, css, caching

I just encountered a line like this in the head of a (program generated) web page, any ideas what purpose the number and ID serve?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact.css?4131768016" id="pagesheet"/>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460389/browser-caching-of-css-files which explains better than I could

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's so that the client's browser doesn't use a cached stylesheet when the page is loaded. That number is probably generated programatically, on the server-side. It will be different every time the page is loaded and so the browser will identify that stylesheet as different from the one in the cache and hence, re-download it.