# CSS style not updating in web browser

Tags: html, css

I have recently updated a CSS file onto the web with a slight change in, to make a certain text `blue` instead of `red`:

```
p.melding{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue; /*red earlier*/
}
```

The file has been updated online, but the change is not displaying online (nor any other changes I have made to the CSS script). When I look in the style editor in the web developer tool in Firefox, it says `red`. (When I change it in that editor it changes to blue.)

The style sheet seems to work in general, so shouldn't be an issue with the code there. Below are the relevant parts of my *html/php* file. Although this has been written by someone else (professional) and there has not been a problem with it earlier, so I think the problem lies somewhere else.

The link to the stylesheet:

```
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  </head>
```

and the php code concerning the class in question:

```
<?php
  if (isset($melding)) {
    echo "            <p class=\"melding\">$melding</p>\n";
  }
?>
```

Any ideas why the changes to my CSS file are not showing online?

Comment: assuming you have a `<p>` tag holding the "melding" class(?) Show us the rest of your code. You tagged as PHP/HTML but nothing to support the question really.

Comment: You must to show the HTML and the CSS code that is applying to the element, but all the css, not only this part.

Comment: Don't let PHP confuse you. It's a PREprocessor. It does all it's jobs on the server, and sends out a pure text/html (or whatever you tell it to `echo`). Check if your path is correct, check if your class is correct, also try to change the filename in `link` tag to something like `stil.css?v2` (so that the browser won't use the CSS file that's in its cache).

Comment: Try <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css?v=1" type="text/css" media="screen" /> to eliminate caching issues.

Comment: add live website URL or add in snippet.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`F5` on your browser

Comment: that... or a hard refresh. FF for one, is bad for that, if you're using FF.

Comment: you can see inherited from class in your browser firebug styles

Comment: @todinov Even better `<link href="/stylesheet.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` ;-) otherwise OP would need to use `href="stil.css?v=2"` (3,4,5) etc. if further changes are made.

Comment: @Fred-ii- using the current time would be okay for development, but in production would cause the stylesheet to be downloaded on every visit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Personally I'm not sure this is a good idea as every time a user views the page the revision time (`.css?<?php the_time() ?>`) will change.

Comment: @Aaron ah, you may have a point there ;-)

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460389/browser-caching-of-css-files

Comment: `Ctrl`+`F5` did the trick! Didn't know about that quick fix, thanks a lot! I guess it was a caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the page had not been cached. Doing `Ctrl+F5` (in the web browser) solved it.

The caching depends on the browser and the server, so it varies if this is an issue or not when updating CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope that it works for you:

```
p.melding{
   font-weight: bold !important;
   color: blue !important; 
}
```

It usually happens, if your CSS is getting overridden again, maybe by some other file.

A couple notes about [using `!important`.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/)

Hope it helps you out!!

Comment: He has said it shows as red when he inspects the element.

Comment: Thats rite, but it also happens, if the css is getting overridden in someother file. As CSS follows a top-down approach. The later css is the one that is captured and applied.

Comment: You can read more about the !important here. http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/

Comment: Yes, CSS can be overridden. But in this case if you inspect the element (at least in Chrome), the prioritised rule is what's shown first - therefore adding `!important` won't do anything. His changes are not being shown. It's more likely to be a cached CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
<?php
  if (isset($melding)) {
  echo "            <p class='melding'>$melding</p>\n";
  }
?>
```

If that does not work clear the browser cache and restart the browser.