# CSS background image wont go away

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm working on a site with multiple people right now, were using a bootstrap css template, someone added a background image with the following code.

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background: url('../img/bgPhoto.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

My issue is, no matter what I do to change/ get rid of the image, it wont go away, I've restarted my IDE, I've restarted my FTP, I've even the code and the image itself, heck I've even restarted my computer. But the haunting image remains.

I've tried small things like

```
background-image: none !important;
```

but that doesn't even work. Am I missing something super simple here?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache on your web browser?

Comment: Chrome Dev tools > Inspect that background image > check if there are multiple CSS background image declarations

Comment: @Gendarme - I have cleared the cache, but still there

Comment: @Drakes - i double checked and didnt see any other declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a browser cache issue. The browser is serving a cached version your css file. You can try clearing your browser cache or appending a parameter to your css file name.:

link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style.css?nocache={timestamp}" type="text/css"

Similar issue:
    [Browser Caching of CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460389/browser-caching-of-css-files)

Comment: THANKS! i cleared the cache multiple times, didn't seem to help but i appended a parameter to it, that seems to be working! I need to do some more research on the matter still, but that seems to fix my issue for now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
background: none !important;
```

If it's not work, please attach screenshot or link to your site