# CSS sometimes loads, sometimes not

Tags: css, stylesheet

Is this common? When I save my external stylesheet and update my browser the changes applies directly for the most of the time, but after a while when I save again the changes does not apply at all. Nothing I do to the stylesheet at this moment will apply for a while. Then it continues to work for a while and then it stops working again for a while and so on and on and so on.

Any thoughts?

Take care

Comment: The browser is caching it

Comment: @CupofJava Can you explain a little more about it? I do not know anything about cashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. In general browsers try to cache any resource they have loaded previously.

Checkout this post that details this behaviour a bit more: [Browser Caching of CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460389/browser-caching-of-css-files)

Comment: Great Peter. Thanks

Comment: Can you please mark this question as answered if this is what you have been looking for (accept this answer)?