# My CSS doesn't change, why?

Tags: html, css, caching, web, frontend

So after many weeks, I got back to coding and I've got a problem.

The project I was working on contains the basic stuff of a PHP site and now I'm trying to re-design my homepage.

The problem is, that everytime I delete or change something in the CSS, the design never changes as if it's like frozen or something, and it happens for every page. When I delete the link to the CSS in my HTML, the design goes away. Here's the code:

```js
var scrolled=0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#master").click(function() {
            $("#holder").slideToggle('slow');
        });
                
        $("#down").on("click" ,function() {
            scrolled=scrolled+300;
            $("#solut").animate({
                scrollTop: scrolled
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
@font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
      src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #e0e0e0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="assets/logo.png" />
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
          //code goes here: bunch of divs and texts
        </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: The stylesheet is likely being cached. Try changing the link to read "`css/index.css?v=1`" (under most configurations, anything after the question mark will be ignored - put whatever you like) to see if this is the case.

Comment: Are you loading locally?

Comment: [For more information about caching...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460389/browser-caching-of-css-files)

Comment: Try to reload the page with ctrl+F5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting back to an old project without a **short run-through-guide**, **readme** or a **basic list of automated tasks** can lead to several, unwanted side effects, when running and testing the website.

Here are some of what I've met before from the top of my head:

- **Browser cache:** Open DevTools in Chrome, then reload the page by clicking **Empty Cache and Hard Reload** *(Ctrl+Shift+F5)*. If it doesn't help, give your CSS a name like: ([**more on cache-bursting**](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)): 
  `<link href="css/index.css?v=1.0.1" rel="stylesheet" />`
- **Framework cache:** If you use a framework with **resource caching**, delete/empty it. It depends on what framework you use, if any.
- **CSS Transpiler does not run:** If you use some transpiler ([SASS](https://sass-lang.com/), [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), etc.), sometimes running of the transpilation is forgotten.
- **Testing on mobile devices:** They can and do cache often, just use cache-bursting during development.
- **Wrong paths/inability to access files**: Check your **[webserver logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)** to get what's wrong.
- **Not REALLY editing the file**: If you prefer an IDE (e.g.: [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/specials/idea/idea.html) ;)) and when you edit the specific file, save it, then upload it (e.g.: via FTP), it can happen, that the **specific file won't get updated**. **[More on this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm)**.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a caching issue. But have you double checked your developers tool to see if the CSS is carrying over? Sometimes I make small mistakes of linking the file incorrectly - forgetting to go back a folder "../css/index.css