# Need to clear browser data first before seeing changes to bootstrap design

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, browser-cache

I have an issue. I'm currently using bootsrap version 4.1.2 on xampp. The problem is everytime i make a change to the bootstrap.css file, i need to clear my browser data before i can see those changes. If i dont clear it, the design will look the same as before. Thanks

Comment: That's normal, as CSS is cached by the browser to reduce load. Do a hard-reload and you should be able to see the changes immediately.

Comment: @Grey take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with PHP.

This is a simple case of caching, which the browser performs to speed up load time.

This can be prevented, amongst all other ways, by using this example -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/460442/6382913