# Spring Boot Applying Older Version of CSS File to JSP

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, jsp, el

I have a Spring Boot project which has a MainMenu.jsp which is as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <div class="navheader">
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
            <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="${contextPath}/logout">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </form>

            <h2>Welcome ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a onclick="document.forms['logoutForm'].submit()">Logout</a></h2>
        </c:if>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Groups</li>
        <li>Frameworks</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using a style.css file located under resources/static/css, and my browser locates it successfully as it does not return a 404 error. However any changes I make are not reflected - it appears to be using an older version of the CSS. I suspect it is using the CSS from style.css before I changed the style sheet's href from

`"/css/style.css"` to `"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css"`

If the path is correct, why isn't it applying my CSS? If the path isn't correct, why is it using an older version and not giving a 404 for not finding the file?

Edit: my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>samuelB</groupId>
    <artifactId>capripol</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Capripol</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers cache css files based on settings, in your development setup you can disable cache in the browser to always load the new files when the site loads. For example if you are using Chrome you can do so by ticking the Disable Cache box in Developer tools, network tab.

[image]

For production system, you can avoid css caching by using a version number in the css filename.

also read : [Browser Caching of CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460389/browser-caching-of-css-files)

Comment: Edit: It now seems to be working, I suppose chrome didn't refresh properly after checking the disable cache